# Add new liste to an existant dictionary with multiple liste value

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, flask

i need to project a query to rack servers in tables format, but my problem is how to add empty unit values between used units.
this is my code:

```
import io
import pandas as pd

query = '''servers1 - 15 - 17
server2 - 20 - 25
firewall - 2 - 4
NAS - 10 - 15'''

data = {}
counter = {}

with io.StringIO(query) as fh:
    for line in fh:
        line = line.strip()
        name, start, end = line.split(' - ')
        start = int(start)
        end = int(end)
        counter.update({ name : [start, end, end-start+1] })
df = pd.DataFrame(counter).T
df = df.sort_values(by=0, ascending=False)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.columns = ['name','start','end', 'total_units']
print(df)
```

this code geve me this result :

[image: Image1]

I need to add empty units between used units:

[image: Image2]

Ex: between unit 2 and unit 10 there are 5 empty units, I need to add them to the counter dictionary, and the result must be shown as (image 2)

Comment: Please specify more details about the question.

Comment: example :  between unit 2 and unit 10 there are 5 empty units, I need to add them to the counter dictionary, and the result must be shown as (image 2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your requirements correctly.
The following example lists all occupied and vacant positions in order.
The data is read line by line and added to a list as a tuple. Sorting can then be carried out using the start indices so that all assignments are available in sequence and can also be checked for duplicates. However, it is still possible to enter names twice.
Within the iteration over the sorted sections, the resulting free spaces and the entries are successively added to a new list. This list represents the ordered rows of the created DataFrame.

```
import io
import pandas as pd
from collections import namedtuple

COLUMNS = ['name', 'start', 'end', 'units']
Section = namedtuple('Section', COLUMNS)

def parse_rows(query, limit=40):
    sections = []
    with io.StringIO(query) as fh:
        for ln in fh:
            name, start, end = ln.strip().split(' - ', 2)
            start, end = int(start), int(end)
            assert 0 < start and start <= end <= limit, 'Incorrect declaration'
            sections.append(Section(name, start, end, end - start + 1))

    last = 0
    rows = []

    for s in sorted(sections, key=lambda x: x.start):
        assert 0 < s.start - last, 'Double assignment'
        units = s.start - last - 1
        if units > 0: rows.append(Section('empty', last + 1, s.start - 1, units))
        rows.append(s)
        last = s.end

    if limit - last:
        rows.append(Section('empty', last + 1, limit, limit - last))

    return rows

limit = 40
query = '''servers1 - 16 - 18
server2 - 20 - 25
firewall - 2 - 4
NAS - 10 - 15'''

rows = parse_rows(query, limit)
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=COLUMNS)
print(df)
```

The result is the following output.

```
       name  start  end  units
0     empty      1    1      1
1  firewall      2    4      3
2     empty      5    9      5
3       NAS     10   15      6
4  servers1     16   18      3
5     empty     19   19      1
6   server2     20   25      6
7     empty     26   40     15
```

Comment: thank you so much, that is precisely what I want... thank you